# Button gets covered by Navigation Bar while using Fragments with TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

Here is the screenshot of my problem. As you can see, on the very right bottom of the screen my floating button is covered by the navigation bar. Could anyone help me with this? I am already using padding on my layout.

I tried using android:fitsSystemWindows="true", but it didn't help.

[image]

XML File for the fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addNewReminderButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/md_amber_500"
    app:elevation="4dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the XML containing Toolbar, AppBar and so on.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MaterialTheme" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please, **share** your xml file.

Comment: XML file for the fragment uploaded.

Comment: Please ignore "android:layout_gravity", it remained from trying to use LinearLayout.

Comment: Where is your TabLayout ? Do you use any `<include>` ?

Comment: I put that in my activity_main.xml, it is uploaded now too.

Comment: Hi, @Meetz! Did you solve your problem? I have the same problem and my only idea is to remove `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` part and add padding: `android:paddingTop="105dp"` but that's not so clever solution.